# Creation of account ids

Tags: testing, unit-tests, multisig

**A brief context:** I want to deliver [the test.](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/354)

**The exact context:** Creation of `account_id`'s (first point in an outline).

**Question:** Do I correctly create `account_id` in the context of my task. Should I firstly create signatories?

```
let account_id = Self::multi_account_id(&signatories, 2);
```

In the documentation of `multi_account_id` is written:

> NOTE: who must be sorted. If it is not, then you'll get the wrong
> answer.

Can anybody explain why `who` must be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples.

You can find the examples here: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/b2e1c5bb89a6ab9486fc3c42b0da4f7f064ec1e5/pallet/account-migration/src/tests.rs#L94

Regarding your second question, please refer to this link: [What does it mean in pallet_multisig for accounts to be sorted?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9895/what-does-it-mean-in-pallet-multisig-for-accounts-to-be-sorted).